# Mobile Security Products accessing system data/other app apks on Non-Rooted androids to find vulnerability

Tags: android, security

The discussion is for NON Rooted android phones.

McAfee's Mobile Security, Avast's Theft Aware etc all have some security features that seem to violate Android's sandbox architecture. Eg : Scanning system files + User's  other apps directories, rating apps installed on the phone based on their permissions, resources being accessed etc.

I am just a beginner and have just started reading about the basic building blocks of android security. I have used McAfee's Mobile security and am a little confused how is it able to implement features like Security scan and App Review/Protection on a non rooted phone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the scanner can read other apps' private files, but their public files may be accessible, and [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) shows an external app a fair amount of information.

Comment: Ok but Im not very sure if PackageManager will allow another app(a security product) to parse through all the system and user directories and check all xml, png, gifs etc? During the scan process, the security products displays what all files(along with the directory path) are they scanning in realtime !

Comment: thats what all of them are saying : "Like Trend Micro Mobile Security for Android ($3.99 direct), the app offers a full antivirus scan, especially important in light of the recent spate of Android malware. Users can run a scan on demand or set up a schedule for automated scanning. Lookout will also warn if you install a known spyware app and offer to uninstall it." http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2381762,00.asp